Can dotnet test report which test it is currently working on
When running dotnet test (NUnit test project), the log only seems to contain information on the tests it has already completed. As far as I have been able to find out, it does not log which test(s) it is currently working on. If one test "hangs", this makes it harder to identify which test is causing the problem, especially when running large test suites.
Is there a way to make dotnet test log when it has started exceution of a test?
